# How to track every PHP file located in a folder with Tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind CSS in my projects and I want to include all of my PHP files in `tailwind.config.js` file. I want to use wildcards, but it doesn't seem to work.

This works:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./${themePath}/index.php",
    "./${themePath}/header.php",
    "./${themePath}/footer.php",
  ],
}
```

This doesn't:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./${themePath}/*.{php}",
    "./${themePath}/**/*.{php}",
  ],
}
```

I use Laravel Mix for asset compilation, Tailwind is of course included in `webpack.min.js` file and it works well if I specify the file path in Tailwind's config - wildcards don't work however.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does `./${themePath}/*.php` or `./${themePath}/**/*.php` work? Doesn't really explain why the bracket extension syntax isn't working... but might be worth a try if you haven't yet.

Comment: @methodical No, it doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to be using some third-party library that can search for those files, like [fast-glob](https://github.com/mrmlnc/fast-glob) (glob library for Node.js).

```
module.exports = {
    content: require('fast-glob').sync([
        './${themePath}/**/*.{php}',
    ]),
}
```

Works.